# Local settings and message dialog in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store

I know how to display a message box only once in **windows phone apps**, below is the code

```
if (!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("IsThirdLaunchDone"))
{
     MessageBox.Show("Click on '...', go to settings and select your city and country.");
     IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["IsThirdLaunchDone"] = true;
}
```

But am trying to port the same for my **windows 8 app** but couldn't get it.

```
if (!ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Containers.ContainsKey("IsThirdLaunchDone"))
{
     //MessageDialog Code goes here
     ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings["IsThirdLaunchDone"] = true; //**Error code**
}
```

**Error** - Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type              'Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer'

Need help!

Comment: What's the error code?  It's hard to tell what *will* fix it if we don't know the error.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Extremely Sorry! I have edited my post, please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you you're trying to access a value on something that does not contain values.  Try something like this instead:

```
if (!ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey("IsThirdLaunchDone"))
{
     //MessageDialog Code goes here
     ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["IsThirdLaunchDone"] = true;
}
```

Note the use of `Values` consistently within the get and set. (instead of `Containers`)